# Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'

Tags: kotlin, gradle, dagger-hilt, kapt

Full info of Errors:
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.

> Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kapt'.
> > Could not resolve com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:compiler.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > No cached version of com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:compiler available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:compiler available for offline mode.

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_agp_internal_javaPreCompileDebug_kaptClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:compiler.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > No cached version of com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:compiler available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:compiler available for offline mode.

I updated all highlighted values in both Gradle files, but my project still don't start. I was creating this project follow this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKz_GyCvitw&list=PLaQox2QQZDpjCmqVPvJ5eDyN26UYEojAt&index=9).
I think it`s problem with Dagger&Hilt, because main errors by functions kapt in Gradle file.
I tried start project in toggle offline mode

My Gradle (Module) file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.movieapp'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.movieapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.31.2-alpha'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.31.2-alpha'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.1.1'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:compiler:4.13.0'
}
```

My Gradle (Project) file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false

    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.41' apply false
}
```